# Adding a view to a UITableViewCell's contentView, places the view in the wrong place

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uitextfield

I seem to be having a problem understanding how subviews work. I have a `UITextfield` and I want to add this to the content view of a `UITableViewCell` so i do this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

   if (cell==nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    }    // Configure the cell...
    UITextField *tf = [textFieldsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    tf.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 12);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tf];
    return cell;
}
```

I assumed that by making the textfields frames origin (0,0) when i add this as a subview to the content view, it will place it in the content view at position (0,0), but this is not happening, it is actually placing it at position (0,0) of the entire cell (the top left most part of the cell).

Unless this has been changed in iOS7, i thought the content view was like this:

[image: content view]
<sub>(source: [idev101.com](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UITableView/cellEditAnatomy.png))</sub>

If so, is there a way i can actually place this in the `contentView` without having to manually define an offset each time?

Comment: The top-left corner of the  `contentView` and the cell are the same unless you are in editing mode.

Comment: ahh maddy thanks, i feel so stupid!

Comment: @TylerDurden That's OK. Sometimes the obvious is hard to see when you've been looking at it too long. Enjoy. :)

Comment: BTW - when you wish to reply to someone, be sure to specify there full username preceded by the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Try This 


       if (cell==nil) 
        {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
        UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

        UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        img.tag=100;
        img.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
        img.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [cell addSubview:img];


        UILabel *lbl= [[UILabel alloc]init];
        lbl.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
        lbl.text=@"ABC";
        lbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        lbl.tag=200;
       [cell addSubview:lbl];


     }
img1=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

NSArray *imgDataArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[arrFields objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"image"]];

for (UIImage *image in imgDataArr)
{
    if (image)
        img1.image =image;
}
[cell addSubview:img1];


UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:200];
[cell addSubview:lbl1];
lbl1.numberOfLines=3;
lbl1.text=[[arrFields objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"Item_No"];
```